# Javascript image "onabort" event not firing in Firefox & Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

I'm trying to work out how to get the `onabort` event of an image element to work. From reading the docs it's meant to fire when a loading page is stopped either from clicking the stop button or firing the stop event.

I can get the following code snippet to work in IE but not in any of the other browsers. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function load(e) {
            alert('img loaded');
        }
        function onaborthandle() {
            alert('on abort hadnle');
        }
        
        function abort() {
            if (window.stop) {
                window.stop();
            }
            else {
                document.execCommand("Stop", false);
            }
        }
    </script>

    <img id="testimg" onabort="alert('abort inline');" />
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var img = document.getElementById('testimg');
        
        img.onload = load;
        img.src = 'http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png';
        
        abort();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nothing is wrong, onabort and onerror are not supported in ff, and apparently in chrome too.
although I read somewhere that the event will not work on local system files, but on files hosted on the web, not sure about it.

Comment: I have the onerror event hooked up and it does fire when the image src doesn't exist. It's just the onabort that doesn't work. I've researched a bit further and it does appear that onabort is IE only :(

Comment: im not really sure WHY you need the onabort event, but maybe you can find another way to do the same thing?

Comment: The problem I was trying to solve was not requesting an image which returns a session cookie while it is already downloading. I solved the problem in a different way by dropping any attempts to download the image if it was downloaded in the last 10 seconds. It's not perfect but it works :)

Comment: The article [Preloading images using javascript, the right way and without frameworks](http://fragged.org/preloading-images-using-javascript-the-right-way-and-without-frameworks_744.html) might be interesting

Answer (score 0):

The onabort event handler is not supported in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, or Safari; it is **only** supported in Internet Explorer.

[Credit: W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onabort.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The `onabort` event is only supported by Internet Explorer and Edge.